# How to create a temporary token for influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

I'd like the frontend to call my backend API to get a temporary token, so that the frontend can directly access the linuxDB. For security, I want this token to be temporary.

I noticed`[here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python#proxy-configuration)` said：

[image]

But he doesn't seem to work. The token is still can be used in 60 min later.

Comment: I am based on the docker running influxDB. My image is: influxdb: 2.6-alpine

Comment: Were you able to find the answer?